# R data.tables: ordering and summing with group in one go?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following three lines in R:

```
dt <- data.table(r)
dt <- dt[,list(d=sum(distance)), by=list(pid, person1, person2)]
dt <- dt[order(pid, d)]
```

How can I combine the second two into one statement? Additionally, can I pass some SQL-like `LIMIT` factor so I only have ten rows per pid, person1, person2 combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in one statement, this should work:

```
dt <- dt[,list(d=sum(distance)), by=list(pid, person1, person2)][order(pid, d)]
```

For the limiting, try using `head`. I'm not sure what you're getting at, though. The output of the above statement should have one row per pid, person1, person2 combination.

Also, please provide a small reproducible example of the data you're working with.